# Angularjs infinite scroll fails to load additional records

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a beginner  to angularjs and ionic and i'm implementing infinite scroll, with my current script when it loads the second set of records, it not able to capture the `lastid` and the new generated records to pass it. 
For example when the page loads for the first time (displaying 2 records at a time) and the `lastid` is 10 when a user scroll to the bottom of the page it passes the lastid 10 to get the next set of records when you scroll down again, it passes that same `lastid` of 10 instead of 8

```
$scope.lastid = "";
$http.get('http://localhost/myapp/feeds.php').success(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.feeds=data;
        $scope.lastid = $scope.feeds[$scope.feeds.length - 1].user_id;
         });

       $scope.addMoreItem = function(){
    $http.get('http://localhost/myapp/feeds_more.php?user_id='+$scope.lastid).success(function(data){
        $scope.temp=data;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.temp.length - 1; i++) {
          $scope.feeds.push($scope.temp[i]);
          if(i == $scope.temp.length - 1){
              $scope.lastid = $scope.temp[i].user_id;
          }
        }   
    }); 
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

};
```

HTML

```
<ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="addMoreItem()"  distance="1%"> </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

And one thing is before the first record displays the chrome console read a lot of this error:`Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` and when the page is still it automatically reloads the same records again

Comment: You'll need to add more info if you want an answer. Does the console show some error? Is the GET request successful?

Comment: the console brings out no error. When i place in there manual GET values. it does work

Comment: i've made edit to the question